# Turn off an iMac's screen in single user mode

Tags: command-line, mac, display, imac

I have an old (yet fairly powerful) iMac that I would like to be able to use for servers. Obviously, the best way to run a server would be to boot it up into single user mode/verbose mode for maximum performance. However, I am worried about screen burn in, and I would like to know if there is a way to turn off the display while the server is running in single user mode. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neither mode will do what you want. Single-user mode doesn't start most of the OS (including server processes, networking, ... pretty much anything useful). Verbose mode, on the other hand, just displays console output during startup, but once startup has finished everything runs normally (including the windowing interface). Console mode ([enter ">console" as the username at the login screen](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020318020806482) sounds much more like what you want. But I'm not sure how to turn off the display in that mode...

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.danrodney.com/mac/

Ctrl + Shift + Eject should turn off the display.

If that does not work, from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239439/command-to-sleep-display-osx).

http://www.malcolmhall.com/products/sleepdisplay/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was aware of those and they only work if you are in a GUI. I am asking about single user mode. You boot up into that if you hold Command + S at system startup. It is just a terminal.